# how to get data from the textfield in RadListView itemTemplate (Nativescript)?

Tags: nativescript

I could not solve the below question for Nativescript, and have google search, and try many different ways.

```
<lv:RadListView items="{{ data }}" > 
   <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>  

            <StackLayout>
                <TextField text="{{ data1 }}" />  
                <TextField text="{{ data2 }}" />
            </StackLayout>         

    </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
 </lv:RadListView>
```

**Question**
If the user key in the above 10 different index TextFields of data1 and data2 in the itemTemplate,
how to get the 10 different index TextFields of data1 and data2 ?

Appreciate anyone who could help to solve the above question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question you need to know the which item is tapped/ selected based on the index and this way have access to the specific bound values.
If that is the case you can use [ListViewEventData](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/listvieweventdata.html) and access the unique item [index](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/listvieweventdata.html#index) for each tapped or selected item. Basic example demonstrating using the index to apply different styles can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/blob/ec874feb58c483fcb2b1ff1995383d65319cec2a/sdk/app/listview/item-loading/item-loading.ts#L15-L26) - based on this approach you can access the index of the tapped item on [itemTap event](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#itemtapevent)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Can I get all the index and data by using below selectall without using itemTap event ? 

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/api/classes/radlistview.html#selectall